# TCP socket timeout or no data to read

Tags: c, sockets

How can I recognize if socket timeouted or there are no further data?

I have this:

```
setsockopt(cli_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));  //5 sec timeout
while(1)
{
  l = recv(socket, ...);
  if(l < 0)
    break;
}
```

after I check if `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` are set, but they are set even if timeout didn't happen. I need to perform different actions depending on if connection timeouted or i am done successfully reading

Comment: What do you mean by "they are set even if timeout didn't happen"? They can't ever *both* be "set" since what they are is possible values of `errno` and they are not equal.

Comment: I mean that I always fall into if condition even if I dont want to

Comment: But that's a completely different thing from whether `errno==EWOULDBLOCK` or `errno==EAGAIN`.

Comment: Read the manual, it says that if the connection is closed recv will returns 0, if timed out <0  and >0 means you read something.

Comment: You are mistaken. They are *not* set even if timeout didn't happen. You need to check whether `recv()` returned -1 *before* examining `errno`. Left-over values from prior system calls are not disturbed by a successful system call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three options to check for timeouts:

1. Use `SO_RCVTIMEO` (which I assume you're doing, you really should show that part!). Then you will have `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`. If you get this error on a blocking socket you *know* it has timed out, otherwise the function would not have returned with the specific error set. For non-blocking socket this method makes no sense.

   Also note that the arguments to `setsockopt()` for this option differs on different platform. On POSIX platforms the argument is a pointer to a `struct timeval`, while on Windows it's a pointer to a `DWORD`. Also note that on Windows the `recv` function actually *returns* `WSAETIMEDOUT` on timeout.

   If the socket times out using `SO_RCVTIMEO` then it's in an indeterminate state and should not be used any more. Close it and reconnect.
2. Use `SO_KEEPALIVE`. There is no standard or platform-independent way of setting the timeout which defaults to something like two hours. The `recv` call should fail with `errno` set to `ETIMEDOUT`.
3. Add keep-alive signalling into your protocol.

---

Using method one, on a POSIX platform (like Linux or OSX), you check something like this

```
l = recv(...)
if (l < 0)
{
    if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)
    {
        // Timeout, handle it somehow
    }

    break;  // Exit receiving loop
}
```

The important part here is to not check `errno` unless you actually *know* there is an error. If `recv` returns with a non-negative value then the value of `errno` is indeterminate.

You also need to check for *both* `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN` as it's not specified which of them will be set.

Comment: could you show an example? I think I have conditions in wrong order

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if ETIMEDOUT is setted.
From the [man page of recv(3):](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv)

> ETIMEDOUT
>   The connection timed out during connection establishment, or due to a transmission timeout on active connection.

Comment: OP is using `recv()`, so a timeout "during connection establishment, or due to a transmission timeout on active connection" can't happen.

Comment: Can somebody tell me what is meant by "due to a transmission timeout on active connection" ? what is meant by "transmission" while using "recv" ??